# How do i display data in front-end in descending order for year born given in a single row of mysql

Tags: php

I am trying to array year in descending order associated with some other data which is fetched from mysql database in php

```
My Table
username   familyperson1     yearofbirth1     cityname1     familyperson2     yearofbirth2     cityname2      familyperson3   yearofbirth3   cityname3 ...
ptbarn     John              1985             New York      Smit              2001             San Fransisco  Kate            1966           Houston   ...
```

My mysql fetch query:

```
require("connect.php");
$srno = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table_name WHERE username='" . $srno . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$username = $row['username'];
$familyperson1 = $row['familyperson1'];
$yearofbirth1 = $row['yearofbirth1'];
$cityname1 = $row['cityname1'];
$familyperson2 = $row['familyperson2'];
$yearofbirth2 = $row['yearofbirth2'];
$cityname2 = $row['cityname2'];
$familyperson3 = $row['familyperson2'];
$yearofbirth3 = $row['yearofbirth2'];
$cityname3 = $row['cityname2'];
...
}
```

I request you to please not comment on mysqli on this, that i intent to change later.

Below is the query i fetch from mysql database

```
echo 'Family members of' . $username . ':<br>';
echo $familyperson1 . 'is born in the year' . $yearofbirth1 . 'and stays in the city' . $cityname1 . '<br>';
echo $familyperson2 . 'is born in the year' . $yearofbirth2 . 'and stays in the city' . $cityname2 . '<br>';
echo $familyperson3 . 'is born in the year' . $yearofbirth3 . 'and stays in the city' . $cityname3 . '<br>';
echo $familyperson4 . 'is born in the year' . $yearofbirth4 . 'and stays in the city' . $cityname4 . '<br>';
echo $familyperson5 . 'is born in the year' . $yearofbirth5 . 'and stays in the city' . $cityname5 . '<br>';
```

Now i want that if $yearofbirth4 is youngest it should echo on top and descents and so on and so forth.

Although, the result is:

```
Family members of ptbarn:
John is born in the year 1985 and stays in city New York.
Smit is born in the year 2001 and stays in city San Fransisco.
Kate is born in the year 1966 and stays in city Houston.
Papa is born in the year 2005 and stays in city Las Vegas.
Rony is born in the year 2002 and stays in city San Diego.
```

The result i want is:

```
Family members of ptbarn:
Papa is born in the year 2005 and stays in city Las Vegas.
Rony is born in the year 2002 and stays in city San Diego.
Smit is born in the year 2001 and stays in city San Fransisco.
John is born in the year 1985 and stays in city New York.
Kate is born in the year 1966 and stays in city Houston.
```

I tried this code (from w3schools):

```
echo 'Family members of' . $username . ':<br>';
$numbers = array($yearofbirth1, $yearofbirth2, $yearofbirth3, $yearofbirth4, $yearofbirth5);
rsort($numbers);

$arrlength = count($numbers);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo $familyperson1 . 'is born in the year' . $numbers[$x] . 'and stays in the city' . $cityname1;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

And the result i got was:

```
Family members of ptbarn:
John is born in the year 2005 and stays in city New York.
John is born in the year 2002 and stays in city New York.
John is born in the year 2001 and stays in city New York.
John is born in the year 1985 and stays in city New York.
John is born in the year 1966 and stays in city New York.
```

It's logical that I am doing it wrong above, request help.

Added info: The limit of data is only 5 per user in this in mysql row.

Comment: This code has a smell, and I would think you could just use `ORDER BY` in your query with `LIMIT 5`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i suppose ORDER BY is used if data is in column, right? but Sir, the data is in row.

Comment: Then you should normalize your data and get it into rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arsort instead of rsort which will sort array in reverse order and maintain index association.

```
$yearofbirth1=1985; 
$yearofbirth2=2001; 
$yearofbirth3=1966; 
$yearofbirth4=2005;
$yearofbirth5=2002;

$numbers = array($yearofbirth1, $yearofbirth2, $yearofbirth3, 
$yearofbirth4, $yearofbirth5);
arsort($numbers);

print_r($numbers);

//Array ( [3] => 2005 [4] => 2002 [1] => 2001 [0] => 1985 [2] => 1966 )

$familyperson1 = "a";
$familyperson2 = "b";
$familyperson3 = "c";
$familyperson4 = "d";
$familyperson5 = "e"; 

foreach($numbers as $k=>$v) {
    echo ${'familyperson' . ($k+1)} . ' is born in the year' . $numbers[$k] ;  
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
d is born in the year2005
e is born in the year2002
b is born in the year2001
a is born in the year1985
c is born in the year1966
```

Comment: Undefined variable: familyperson5

Comment: try now...I have changed the variable names

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

this rsort() is sorted in only your variable but your mysql result is in asc order so you can use

```
SELECT name, birth FROM pet ORDER BY birth DESC;
```

Comment: you just copy pasted my code.. if you see, i have used rsort.

Comment: i have edit my question as per your request and added mysql fetch data. please have a look.